# How to save node updates switching between the "Edit" and "View" tabs in Drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, cck, autosave

Users are complaining of losing there work when switching between the "Edit" and "View" tabs in Drupal 6. I have tried to explain there is a preview button at the bottom but with multiple users constantly getting this wrong I thought it would be best to have a "autosave" on the switch of views.

I tried the Autosave module but doesn't seem to work with my install. Any ideas?

Many Thanks,

Axel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went for the [onbeforeunload](http://drupal.org/project/onbeforeunload/) and [dirty forms](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CCwQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdrupal.org%2Fproject%2Fdirtyforms&ei=HQX-TI-5FIyqhAeVj5yuCw&usg=AFQjCNGrwZ50krqRDQEBSzpoiYc3IvqqeQ&sig2=-wXqve8AcvvdmuVzPR7qVw) option.

This simply just uses javascript to warn the user that there work is not saved.

Answer (score 1):

http://drupal.org/project/autosave
Use this module and attach a click event handler to the view tab that triggers an autosave.

Comment: Why not? An alternative approach is to change the link of the view tab to trigger the preview button below the node form. This can be accomplished with only a few lines of JavaScript. However if you need a fallback for non-JS users, you have to alter the menu.